# Do type-changing static abilities allow triggering?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have [March of the Machines](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=March%20of%20the%20Machines) and [Soul Warden](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Soul%20Warden) on the battlefield, what happens when I cast a non-creature artifact like [Azorius Signet](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Azorius%20Signet)? When exactly does the card type change?

Comment: One could call the argument irrelevant because the deck with march of the machines and soul warden will lose to just about anything but catacomb slug. :-)

Comment: The signet will come into play as a creature and trigger the wardens ability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Soul Warden's ability will trigger.

---

> 603.6d Normally, objects that exist immediately after an event are checked to see if the event matched any trigger conditions. [...]

That means it's the types the Signet has on the battlefield that are checked by Soul Warden's triggered ability.

> 604.1. Static abilities do something all the time rather than being activated or triggered. They are written as statements, and they’re simply true.

That means there isn't a moment that a non-creature artifact on the battlefield is not affected by March of the Machine.

As such, the Signet is seen as a creature by Soul Warden's triggered ability, and it will trigger.